# Implement factory function that returns a struct with closure

Tags: generics, rust, closures, traits

Assume we have a struct `StoresFnMut` that stores a closure with the help of a generic parameter. It should be stored via a generic type field in order to ensure static dispatch. The stored closure is usually quite simple (e.g., a single number addition), but called very often. So dynamic dispatch would have quite a performance impact.

```
struct StoresFnMut<F: FnMut(i32) -> i32> {
    pub func: F,
}
```

Now we want a factory function that returns a concrete instance of `StoresFnMut`, which combines the struct with some kind of default closure:

```
fn with_concrete_fn<F: FnMut(i32) -> i32>(vec: &[i32]) -> StoresFnMut<F> {
    StoresFnMut {
        func: |x| vec.get(x),
    }
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let v = vec![0, 0, 0];
    let _ = with_concrete_fn(&v);
}
```

However, it fails to compile, and the compiler gives the help that

> every closure has a distinct type and so could not always match the
> caller-chosen type of parameter `F`

I understand the problem, have read quite some questions around this topic and know some workarounds like for example storing the closure in `StoresFnMut` in a `Box<dyn FnMut>`. However, I really want to have it with static dispatch in `StoresFnMut`. In all the related questions on SO

What would be a possible approach to implement a factory function that returns a concrete instance of `StoresFnMut` with a default closure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem as you saw is that the way you've declared it, the *caller* gets to choose the generic type, not the function. If instead your function decides the type it should work ok.

```
// Note i32 changed to usize as you're using it to index an array
struct StoresFnMut<F: FnMut(usize) -> i32> {
    pub func: F,
}

// Returning 'a type that implements the right trait' instead of a caller
// defined type. Note the addition of the lifetime as there needs to be
// something tying it to the lifetime of the closure
fn with_concrete_fn(vec: &[i32]) -> StoresFnMut<impl FnMut(usize) -> i32 + '_> {
    StoresFnMut {
        // indexing instead of `get` so it doesn't return an option
        func: |x| vec[x],
    }
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let v = vec![0, 0, 0];
    let _ = with_concrete_fn(&v);
}
```